# help on rooting Note 3

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm trying to find a way to root my phone so I can delete these factory installed apps, make my phone faster etc.

Can someone tell step by step on how to achieve this? Do I need to download something? Etc

Answer (score 2):

**By rooting your device you will lose your warranty and during this process you may brick the device. You are doing it at your risk.**

According to [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-3/development) you can use the [CF-Auto-Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2466423) tool to root Galaxy Note 3. The following instructions come from [Chainfire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=631273)'s post.

> Do I need to download something?

Yes:

- [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) - this will install USB drivers
- [CF-Auto-Root](http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/) - **make sure you download the right file for your device model and Android version!**
- [Odin](http://stockroms.net/file/Tools/ODIN/Odin3v185.zip)

Rooting:

- Your phone must not be connected to computer now.
- Download CF-Auto-Root from the above forum link.
- Extract the archive. You must end up with a file ending in `.tar.md5`.
- Start *Odin* (look in the forum thread for download) and click the PDA button. Browse and select the previously extracted file.
- Turn on phone in *Download* mode:

  - turn off
  - press and hold **Volume Down**, **Home** and **Power**
  - if you are asked to press a button do it
- Connect the USB cable to phone and computer.
- Do **NOT** check *Repartition* and make sure it is not checked!
- Click *Start* in Odin.
- Wait for it to reboot.

Another tutorial can be found [here](http://galaxynote3root.com/galaxy-note-3-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-3/) and includes pictures of the process too.