# Most recent root and flash rom for Verizon Note 3

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-3, verizon

I know this is a super specific question, but I am trying to root and then flash cyanogenmod onto my Verizon Note 3. It seems like security features change constantly for Samsung phones and I have not been able to keep up. Can someone point me in a direction (maybe to a tutorial) that is up to date for flashing roms and rooting.

Ive looked but one says one thing while the other says the opposite.

Comment: Related: [help on rooting Note 3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/91491/16575)